# What are the various pieces of a URL called?

Tags: url

I know a URL is composed of a protocol, a domain, and a path, but what about the other pieces?  I'm trying to give meaningful names to some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple pieces of a URL are:

- protocol
- sub-domain
- domain
- port
- path
- query
- parameters
- fragment

For example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208880+complex+enum
```

can be broken down as:

- protocol: `http://`
- sub-domain: `[None]`
- domain: `stackoverflow.com`
- port: `:80 [by default]`
- path: `/search`
- query: `?`
- parameters: `q=user%3A208880+complex+enum`
- fragment: `[None]`

A more thorough explanation can be found at [`Anatomy of a URL`](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url).